# How to use MSTest to run tests for a namespace.subnamespace

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, mstest

I have a test filter criteria which follows the format `namespace.subnamespace.testClass`. I want to use a new MSTest test filter criteria for *just* `namespace.subnamespace` to run all the test classes in this subnamespace.

I originally tried `dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName=namespace.subnamespace`, which does not work for me. I also tried `dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName~namespace.subnamespace` (swapped `=` for `~`), which does work.

I am curious: does the original approach work at all? It would seem like it should, lest I'm misunderstanding what a "FullyQualifiedName" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FullyQualifiedName` includes the Namespace and the Classname and the Methodname. Hence, the `=` operator won't work, but the `~` contains operator will.

The docs are a bit vague on the operators and their values. [This blog post has been my rescue in many occasions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikramagrawal/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter/).

Also blogged on this topic:

- https://jessehouwing.net/staged-execution-of-tests-in-azure-devops-pipelines/